# Word VBA: How to show a changing selection object when operating within a user dialogue window?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a custom user dialogue for reviewing revisions (of which I post only the code relevant to my question). 
With the command button "FindNextRevision_Click" I jump to the next revision and display the revision properties. With the command button "AcceptRevision_Click" I accept the selected revision.

The code works fine, but when I navigate to the next revision the selection object won't be marked within the text until I leave the dialogue box - which is defeating my whole purpose, because I can't see immediately where the revision I'm operating on is located within the text.

How can I show the selection object when changing it from within a user dialogue box without leaving the dialogue?

```
Public Rev_Selected As Revision

Private Sub FindNextRevision_Click()
    Set Rev_Selected = Selection.NextRevision
    With Rev_Selected
        strRevType = .Type
        strRevAuth = .Author
        strRevDate = .Date
        strRevR = .Range
    End With
    Call MTF_DisplayRevisionProperties(strRevType, strRevAuth, strRevDate, strRevR)
    ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range
end sub

Private Sub AcceptRevision_Click()
    Rev_Selected.Accept
End Sub

Sub MTF_DisplayRevisionProperties(strRevType, strRevAuth, strRevDate, strRevR)
    'some code which is not important for my question
end sub
```

Comment: The form's Show command is modal by default which means that nothing can be done on the object until the form closes. Try to call the form using
    .Show vbModeless

Comment: maybe something like `Selection.HighlightColorIndex = wdGray50`

Comment: I am not able to replicate the problem you are saying. When the above code navigates to next revision, I can see the revision text is selected in the document. I am using Word 2016. Please confirm your word version and whether you are viewing your document in Draft mode or print layout mode, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer (which has now been made obsolete by the comment of Variatus (see above):

Before the line:

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range
```

I added the line:

```
Word.Application.Activate
```

As long as I don't switch the focus to any other application I can follow the changing selection object on the screen. If, however, I switch the focus to another application, i.e. Acrobat Reader and then back to WinWord, the selection object will not be visible any more as long as I don't close the user dialogue.